# MongoDB2.6でのDBRef条件指定検索

Tags: mongodb

例えば
scoreコレクションに

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50f5379785ac77daf3dd4bfd"),
  "user" : {
    "$ref" : "collection_user",
    "$id" : ObjectId("50f5370e85ac77daf3dd4bfb")
  },
  "score" : 100
}
```

userコレクションに

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50f5370e85ac77daf3dd4bfb"),
  "name" : "User1",
  "No"   : 1111
}
```

のようなデータが存在するとき、scoreコレクションにuserコレクションを外部結合のようなことをして、nameで検索条件を指定したり、ソートの条件にしたいと考えています。

mongoDB3.6以上であれば、lookupを使えばなんとなく行けそうな雰囲気はありますが、2.6の場合、実現する方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB v3.2以前にデータベースサーバ側できませんでした。アプリケーション側での結合は必要です。

一つのアプリケーションのpseudoコードのイメージ：

```
users_rs = db.user.find({name: xxxxxx})
user_id_list = []
for doc in users_rs:
  user_id_list.append(doc._id)
scores_rs = db.scores.find({"user.$id": {$in: user_id_list}})
//scoresとusersのデータを合併して
//それあとソーティング
```